# Send message depending on length of array

Tags: javascript, express

I have a problem where I have example document in mongo atlas database:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e517a946364cc48f0ccf1e7"
    },
    "firstName": "checkout1",
    "lastName": "",
    "companyName": "",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "email": "exampleemail@gmail.com",
    "country": "",
    "adress": "",
    "postcode": "",
    "userId": "5daf414818d091616a0d917e",
    "orderedItems": [{
        "_id": "5e03b2072e0c98b9fa62388c",
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Blue shoes",
        "img1": "product4/1.jpg",
        "img2": "product4/2.jpg",
        "cost": 70,
        "color": "blue",
        "quantity": 5
    }],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-02-22T19:01:40.228Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2020-02-22T19:01:40.228Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want to send a message with confirmation about purchased items and their quantity as shown below:

...

```
    const {
       ...
email,
      orderedItems
    } = req.body;
    var user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    let newCheckout = await Checkout.create({

      ...
      email,
      ...
      orderedItems,
      userId: user._id
    });
    const htmlEmail = `
    <div>Title of first ordered item: ${newCheckout.orderedItems[0].title}</div>
    `;

    const mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.MY_TEST_EMAIL_ADRESS,
      to: process.env.MY_EMAIL_ADRESS,
      subject: 'new message',
      replyTo: process.env.MY_EMAIL_ADRESS,
      text: process.env.MY_TEST_EMAIL_ADRESS,
      html: htmlEmail
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {});
```

...

I need this part of code:

```
const htmlEmail = `
        <div>Title of first ordered item: ${newCheckout.orderedItems[0].title}</div>
        `;
```

To map it similar to like in React where I can map the orderedItems array to div elements so in the end, the outcome message would look something like this (user would get all ordered item titles, and the number of div elements would depend on length of array):

```
<div>Item: ${newCheckout.orderedItems[0].title}</div>
<div>Item: ${newCheckout.orderedItems[1].title}</div>
<div>Item: ${newCheckout.orderedItems[2].title}</div>
```

My main question would be is it possible to do without template engines such as Jade, Pug, Mustache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template engines are not a requirement, just iterate by `orderedItems`:

```
const htmlMail = newCheckout.orderedItems.map(i => `<div>Item: ${i.title}</div>`).join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
orderedItems.map(item => `<div>Item: ${item.title}</div>`).join()
```

When you find yourself coming back to StackOverflow to ask about the next step in building your own custom rendering engine, take a minute to look at [Knockout](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/).

It will save you time in the long run, because you are going to want to make more and more customisations, and soon you have spent more time making a hack than you would have making it with a renderer.

Knockout is easy and you send a JSON object and it gets rendered on the client, and you can make customisations to the layout easily and quickly. You'll love it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, I market the first one as accepted though because it was the first one.